# "Object doesn't support property or method 'messageParent'" After login redirect in Office js

Tags: office-js

I am trying to get a dialog to open in order to enter login credentials, but after being redirected back from the login authority I am no longer able to message the parent of the dialog window back with authorization codes or tokens.  If I do not redirect away from the page, I can message back to the parent, but otherwise I get the error in the title.  How can I message the parent (in this case the task pane) window with information from the dialog?

Below is the code I have to open and handle the dialog window:

```
var dialog; 
function authenticate() {
    hideAll();
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('mydomain/Login',
        { height: 50, width: 25 }, dialogCallback);
}

function dialogCallback(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === 'failed') {
        console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
    } else {

    dialog = asyncResult.value;
    dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.
        DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);
    dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.
        DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);
    }
}

function messageHandler(arg) {
    showAll();
    console.log(arg);
    dialog.close();
}

function eventHandler(arg) {
    showAll();
    console.log(arg);
}
```

Here is the code that handles my login screen:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        var code = $('#code').text();
        if (code !== '') {
            console.log(code);
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(code);
        } else {
            console.log('No code received from auth server');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved by making sure I was landing on a page on my domain first.  I was originally directing to a controller which was redirecting from my domain, but hadn't yet returned a page.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a different problem: The url I passed to the `displayDialogAsync` already contained a `_host_Info` query parameter, which seems to decide for office.js whether to be a dialog or not (and therefore exposing the `messageParent` m
ethod).

More info in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/378#issuecomment-713087159)